# Laravel how to delete database record after created 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

How to automatically delete database records created after 7 days? And do I have to place in index.blade.php or something? Maybe some scheduler?

```
public function index()
{
    $results = Test::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
    if (!Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        $results = $results->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id());
    }
    return view('results.index', compact('results'));
}
```

Comment: Cron jobs would do this for you if you are on a linux platform. However, the code snip you have given doesn't seem to demonstrate your intention.

Comment: I'm not using Linux platform. But i will research about it thank you.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Sorry sir i don't understand as well. I'm just using Local Wampserver.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I forgot I'm sorry. Thank you for reminded me that.

Comment: @RukaXing No problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Laravel task scheduling to do this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Shedule a task that runs every week which deletes the posts.

Tasks are defined inside the `schedule` method of the  `App\Console\Kernel` class.

There you can define a closure:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            Test::where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->delete();
        })->weekly();
    }
```

.

Then you have to add a cron job that runs every few minutes (or any time frame you wish) to run these commands.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

.

This will check for due tasks and will run them accordingly.

Hope it helps. Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stale_posts = Test::where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->get();
foreach ($stale_posts as $post) {
   $post->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For things to be automatic in the way I think you mean, you probably want to setup a scheduled task. You can create a simple Artisan command that does the check and deletes the records very quickly.

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Artisan Console - Writing Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#writing-commands)

You would then call this task from the scheduler at some interval. Once a day might be fine atm, depends how critical this accuracy of the database range is.

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Task Scheduling - Defining Schedules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#defining-schedules)

Lacking something like cron or other options that can call the scheduler automatically you would have to call it manually or somehow use the incoming requests as a way to potentially run this task at some interval. If you had a queue going you could fire a job to do this off to the queue.